# Can run daily logrotate without cron?

Tags: linux, logging, cron, logrotate

On my docker, i use amazonlinux:2 at this default enviroment **not install cron**.

I want to use logrotate for rotating log of application every daily. **Can Logrotate work automatic without cron?**

This file /etc/logrotate.d/app_log

```
/home/app/logs/*.log {
    daily
    compress
    maxage 7
    missingok
    notifempty
```

}

Comment: That's not really a programming question.

Comment: @UlrichEckhardt Yeah maybe it's really unrelated to programming but i hope someone who has used logrotate knows the answer. Since I am a programmer but still have to configure this.

Comment: Does amazonlinux use systemd? If so, you can use a systemd [timer](https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/systemd.timer.html).

Comment: @larsks Thanks for answer. I'm not allowed on access on Product environment. I don't know at here was installed cron yet. So I want to know Can Logrotate work automatic without cron or systemd timer?

Comment: No. You need *something* to run it periodically.